# Crashing while making boot partition

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm try to install Ubuntu 14.10 next to the Windows 7. I use something else methode and create:

1. ex4 /boot(500 MB)
2. swap area (2048 MB)
3. ex4 / (19000MB)

But when I try to install Ubuntu, it crashes during the first step:

> **Creating ext4 file system for /boot in partition #9 of SCSI1 (0,0,0)(sda)**
>
> /usr/lib/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 12277 was not found when attempting to remove it Glib.source_remove(self.rows_chanded_id)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded Ubuntu 14.10 and not 13.10? The installer crashing while making partitions was a known issue in Ubuntu 13.10. I know you probably do have 14.10, but just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a special reason, why you use a separate partition as /boot? You could try installing it with only the file system root partition (ext4, mount point "/") and the swap partition. Or just try again with the same configuration, maybe it works this time. It could also be useful to wipe all partitions you don't want to keep (the ones that failed to create or what was in their place before) so you create fresh partitions on unpartitioned area for Ubuntu. Hope one of these suggestions helps you. Good luck!